# Displaying all the images in a folder in image control with 5sec time gap

Tags: wpf, c#-4.0

I have a folder with 1000 images that have the image name in a sequence "ICON000,ICON001 till ICON 999". I need them to be displayed in my WPF image control sequentially with 5sec time delay. i have used a file dialogue box to get the path of the particular folder and the corresponding prefix of the image (ICON). i used the below code

```
string path = null;
string selected_file;
string URI;`enter code here`
openfile.AddExtension = true;
openfile.Filter = "GIF(*.gif)|*.gif|PNG(*.png)|*.png|JPG(*.jpg)|*.jpg|JPEG(*.jpeg)|*.jpeg";
DialogResult result = openfile.ShowDialog();
if (result.ToString() == "OK")
{
selected_file = openfile.FileName;
 Uri uri_temp = new Uri(selected_file);
URI = uri_temp.AbsoluteUri;

 string[] ext = URI.Split('.');
 //textBox1.Text = ext[0];

 string[] ss = ext[0].Split('/');
 int a = ss.Length;

string a1 = ss[a - 1];

string image_prefix = a1.Substring(0, 4);
   string image_no = a1.Substring(4, 3);
   for (int i = 0; i < a-1; i++)
    {
        path = path + ss[i] + "/";
     }
  string path1 = path;

     path = path1 + image_prefix + image_no + "." + ext[1];

   for (int i = 1; i < 999; i++)
    {
        if (i < 10)
       {
           image_no = "00" + i;
        }
       else if (i < 100)
      {
           image_no = "0" + i;
         }
         else
        {
              image_no = i.ToString();
          }
          path = path1 + image_prefix + image_no + "." + ext[1];
           string dasdasd = path;

         string loc = new Uri(path).LocalPath;
           bool asasa = File.Exists(loc);
       if (asasa == true)
          {      System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(5000);
                image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(dasdasd));
           }
             else
             {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show("File not found");
         }
```

But the image is not getting displayed. do the need ful....!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a [DispatcherTimer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatchertimer.aspx) to update the currently displayed image.

```
private DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
private int imageIndex;
private int maxImageIndex;

public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    timer.Tick += TimerTick;
}

private void StartSlideShow(TimeSpan interval, int maxIndex)
{
    imageIndex = 0;
    maxImageIndex = maxIndex;

    timer.Interval = interval;
    timer.Start();
}

private void TimerTick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    image.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(CreatePath(imageIndex)));

    if (++imageIndex >= maxImageIndex)
    {
        ((DispatcherTimer)sender).Stop();
    }
}

private string CreatePath(int index)
{
    // create image file path from index
    // ...
}
```

Start displaying images by calling for example

```
StartSlideShow(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5), 1000);
```

Comment: Thanks Clemens. I used a similar method, not exactly this.

Answer (score 0):

With the call to `Thread.Sleep()` you block the UI thread. So whatever change you make to the UI will not be displayed.

What you should do instead is using a timer. Make `i` (you may want to rename it) a class variable. Set the timer to fire up every 5 seconds. In the timer event, increment `i`, load the next image and set it for the image control. To set the image you have to use the Dispatcher (`Dispatcher.Invoke()`), because you cannot change the UI from a non-UI thread.