# How do I create an array of type ImageSource?

Tags: c#, wpf, imagesource

I am trying to make an array of pictures to set to my image control.  There is a loop that will run through the pictures and display each for a second until it stops on a random picture.

My Approach: I stored the pictures paths in a string which I then put into an array.  Inside my loop I create a new ImageSource and define it by the array item who's turn it is to be displayed.  I believe that the reason my program won't work is that the ImageSource can't pull the image from the file and set it to the image controller fast enough before I sleep the thread to let the picture display for a second.

Here is my code (assume strings are correct paths and I tried countless Thread.Sleep() variables)

This code runs but it only displays the last picture instead of flipping through all of them rapidly then stopping on the last picture.

Would making the array of type ImageSource keep the pictures "on hand" to be displayed faster?
Can WPF support the speed required to get and set images to image controller?
Could my sleep thread be executing too fast before image is set and displayed?

```
 private void ButtonClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
  String[] picArray = new String[] { kristen, justin, brandon, sarah, miles, nina };      
  int i = 0;    
  x = rnd.Next(0,5);

        while (i < rnd.Next(10,50)) 
        {
            ImageSource _currentPic = new BitmapImage(new Uri(picArray[x]));                            
            cImage.Source = _currentPic;
            if (x == 5)
                x = 0;
            else
                x++;

            Thread.Sleep(100);
            i++;
        }

    }
```

The loop stops on a "random" point in the array to randomize whose picture the method ends on.

Thanks ahead of time.

Comment: `ImageSource[]`, It certainly would be faster dependant on how you are storing them, if you are just keeping them local in this method then that would take longer

Comment: Not related to your question, but it appears you're performing some long operations on the UI thread, especially with the `Thread.Sleep()` call there. You may want to consider changing that.

Comment: I tried to use ImageSource[] but it wouldn't let me create and array of that type.  In regards to thread.sleep(), I did not put much thought into it.  Would using a timer be more efficient?

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16978840/1136211) helps.

Answer (score 0):

If this were a normal windows form, you could have used

```
this.Refresh()
```

just before the Sleep() to refresh the screen (displaying the current image).

However, since it's WPF, you have to spawn off that loop into a separate thread (such as `BackgroundWorker`).  Another option would be to set up a `Timer` and just call the contents of the loop every time the timer executes.

Regardless, you have to get that logic off into a new thread for WPF.

Comment: There is no such method in the WPF Window class. You are referring to `Control.Refresh` in WinForms I guess.

Comment: I like the idea of the refresh to ensure that it is the current picture being displayed.  I'm eventually adding a new thread when my program has features that I could use while its running through the picture loop.

Comment: Bah!  Yeah, that's the old Windows forms, not WPF.  Getting into WPF, the problem gets more complicated.  (Working on a revision)

Comment: @muffinMan. You should really do it with a timer, as shown in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16978840/1136211) (or a lot of others). Looping with Thread.Sleep in the dispatcher thread kills your UI.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is not creating any new threads. It's not WPF's fault that your UI will freeze.

Doing `Thread.Sleep()` in the UI Thread is simply going to make your application freeze, no matter if WPF or not.

Also, You don't need any of that in WPF. In WPF, There's `DataBinding`, which removes the need for all these horrible hacks of manipulating the UI in procedural code you might be used to if you are used to some random dinosaur useless framework such as winforms.

Here's the right way to do what you're describing in WPF:

```
<Window x:Class="MiscSamples.SlideShowSample"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="SlideShowSample" Height="300" Width="300">
    <Image Source="{Binding ImageSource}"/>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
public partial class SlideShowSample : Window
{
    public SlideShowSample()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new SlideShowViewModel();
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class SlideShowViewModel:PropertyChangedBase
{
    public const string SourceURL = "http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/";

    private string _imageSource;
    public string ImageSource
    {
        get { return _imageSource; }
        set
        {
            _imageSource = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("ImageSource");
        }
    }

    private System.Threading.Timer _slideShowTimer;
    private System.Random _random = new Random();

    public SlideShowViewModel()
    {
        _slideShowTimer = new Timer(x => OnTimerTick(), null, 1000, 3000);
    }

    private void OnTimerTick()
    {
        ImageSource = SourceURL + _random.Next(1, 10).ToString();
    }
}
```

PropertyChangedBase (MVVM Helper Class):

```
public class PropertyChangedBase:INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke((Action) (() =>
                                                                     {
                                                                         PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
                                                                         if (handler != null) handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
                                                                     }));
        }
    }
```

- See how my code does not manipulate any UI element.
- My sample downloads images from the web, therefore it should be much faster if you use locally stored images.
- Notice how the UI Does NOT freeze at any time. There's still a little delay because the actual image data is being downloaded from the web. That download IS being performed in the UI thread, so you could actually improve my sample to download async, but since you are using locally stored images, it doesn't matter.

Comment: Thank you for showing me such an elaborate sample and clearing up a lot of the issues arising from my dinosaur approach.  I just got an assignment at work so I will test the code as soon as I am done.  I haven't really gotten into official view models really and could potentially need help with some simple clarifications of where classes belong or how to modify it to meet my exact needs.  thanks again

Comment: I just tested this code.  I has issues with the public SlideShowViewModel().  More specifically it said that the timer would not take 4 parameters.

Comment: @muffinMan `Timer` is a `System.Threading.Timer`, check your usings.